# How to use a module in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

Guys im really confused on how to use a module i just installed in Perl.

I installed a [Corelist](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Module-CoreList-2.88/lib/Module/CoreList.pod) module in Perl. And i want to display all the modules that came with Perl 5.006. But there is a hint in doing this by using this code which i dont understand:

```
my %modules = %{ $Module::CoreList::version{5.006} };
```

But when i did this

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %modules = %{$Module::CoreList::version{5.006}};

print %modules;
```

it gives this error: `Module::CoreList::version used only once` . I also tried putting 
`use Module::CoreList;` still no luck

Comment: you need to add this statement `use Module::CoreList;` as suggested by choroba, then it will not give error of `Module::CoreList::version used only once` and `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference`

Comment: Module name is `Module::CoreList;` not `Module::Corelist;`, 'L' is capital in "List".

Comment: it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Thanks @NikhilJain, i missed the capital L in the hash statement. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to print the hash, just add `Data::Dumper` module along with strict and warnings, then

```
print Dumper(\%modules);
```

---

Updated: try something like

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Module::CoreList;
use Data::Dumper;

my  %module  = %{ $Module::CoreList::version{5.006} };

print Dumper (\%module);
```

Comment: same error i get, `Module::CoreList::version used only once` and `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference`

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: Module name is Module::CoreList; not Module::Corelist;, 'L' is capital in "List".

Comment: oh my god i already told you, it doesnt solve my problem. i already replaced it to capital L

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: what happens when you try the exact code given in this answer?

Comment: @ysth: I think, OP didnt try it becuase sometimes we feel that we are doing things correct and later realized that we are doing very small mistake like OP did, like OP missed the capital 'L' in the hash statement That's why i told to focus on the name of the Module.

Answer (score 6):

The name of the module is 'Module::CoreList'. You should put the following line into your programme:

```
use Module::CoreList;
```

Also note the capital `L`. Perl is case sensitive.

Comment: when to use `File::` or `Module::`?

Comment: When the module name includes `File::` or `Module::`.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: Use `File::` when the module's name starts with `File::`, e.g. when using `File::Util`, `File::Spec`, or `File::Find`.

Comment: the module name is the name of the folder i downloaded? in that case its name is `Module-CoreList-2.88` does it matter? am i right?

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: The module name is what the documentation says, or what you told `ppm` or `cpan` to install.

Comment: i still get an error. i edited my post can you check it please

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: "used only once" is a warning, not an error.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: perl module distributions need to be installed, not just downloaded.  usually using one of cpan, cpanplus, cpanm, or ppm.

Comment: and it wont display the list of modules, i have another error too or warning: `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference`

Comment: if you have it in a folder named "Module-CoreList-2.8.8", you did *not* install it, you downloaded it without installing it.  if you think you did install it, would you mind explaining what you did to do that?